# Jquery Equivalent to php $token = md5(uniqid($customerId))

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is there a jquery/javascript code equivalent to this php one? I want to generate a unique 32 character token.

$token = md5(uniqid($customerId))

Comment: if you mean you want something that appears like a guid ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript

Comment: @xandercoded, will this give me the exact output as the php code?